Values in NLog ScopeContext are not present when logging from within matlab
I have a legacy C# application, that now should get a proper logging with NLog 5.0.
The requirement is, that for one process, a property "runId" should be set and during the run, all logging entries should include the value. When two async runs are executed simultaneously, the logging should assign the right run id to the related log message.
my appsettings look as follows:
"NLog": {
    "targets": {
        "mylogfile": {
            "type": "File",
            "fileName": "log.log",
            "layout": {
                "type": "JsonLayout",
                "Attributes": [
                    {
                        "name": "threadid",
                        "layout": "${threadid}"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "runId",
                        "layout": "${scopeproperty:item=runId:whenEmpty=MISSING}"
                    },   
                    {
                        "name": "message",
                        "layout": "${message}"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "processid",
                        "layout": "${processid}"
                    }
                ]
            }                   
            ...

When I now add it to the ScopeContext, it appears for most of the log entries.
var runIdentifier = Guid.NewGuid();
ScopeContext.PushProperty("runId", runIdentifier);

But for some reason, not every log entry has the runId set, and MISSING is displayed, when a Matlab algorithm is executed.
The logger is given to Matlab as an object and Logger.Info is called within matlab, like in C#.
I see the threads change in the log, before the id went missing
{ "threadid": "15", "runId": "80dcc4c2-583f-4967-b01c-1d0fdac574f5", "message": run started, "processid": "188"}
{ "threadid": "6", "runId": "MISSING", "message": Start Execute Matlab Logic, "processid": "188"}
{ "threadid": "17", "runId": "80dcc4c2-583f-4967-b01c-1d0fdac574f5", "message": run ended, "processid": "188"}

Also when I debug, I see, that the id is not set in the current context.
So my assumption is, that a new context is created and things like threadId is take from somewhere else, so it is present.
Is this true? How can I keep the runId inside the matlab script?
